# Sync Yahoo Mail behind a Proxy

Tags: accounts

Okay. This is Weird. Downright weird. But of course, aren't most of the things on Windows Phone and for that matter even Internet Explorer weird!

I have two accounts. Gmail and Yahoo Mail. Both of them are equally important for my life. Till now I was quite happy with my phone easpecially after i got the Windows Phone 7.8 OS.

Everything is going great! And then I move to a college. here for reducing the number of IP Addresses accessing the Internet, They have given us a Proxy server and all internet traffic is routed through this proxy. Now, I want to sync my email! ( i don't wanna wait for a browser to open and then I log in and then I check the emails in a browser. I want to use the native capability of Windows Phone.)

great! Now again, I go to my account and tell Gmail to sync. Perfect! It syncs and I am happy.

Now I do the same to Yahoo Mail and voila! My great day has come to an end. It does not sync.

And I wanna know why it does not sync. And more importantly, Much much more importantly, What can I do so that it would sync each day as do my other Gmail accounts.

My college gave me a proxy IP and a port. (In case that is of any use!)

Comment: Can you connect to Yahoo from a PC based mail client like Outlook or Thunderbird?  Gmail and Yahoo use different ports I believe and the proxy may be blocking the Yahoo IMAP port (993). You might check if Yahoo has alternate ports that may be open on the proxy.

Comment: No I cannot! Actually it is like I can't connect to the Gmail server from Thunderbird! On my PC!

Comment: Have you added the proxy settings to the WiFi connection on your phone?

Comment: Of course I have! Thats the reason why GMail accounts are getting synced..!